# Is there a way to create C library with Cargo?

Tags: static-libraries, rust, rust-cargo, c-api

I need to create a (static) C library that binds to existing crate. Is there any way Cargo can create this C library for me?

I have a crate (e.g. html5ever), and I want Cargo to create a C library based on C-API for that crate.

Comment: You could take a look at [callbacks-from-c-code-to-rust-functions](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/ffi.html#callbacks-from-c-code-to-rust-functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to solve this problem is to create a special crate which stores your  C API. For example if your library is called `foo`, then have inside your main directory another folder alongside `src`/`tests` called `capi`, which will store a special crate `foo_capi` for C API.

```
  foo
   |
   +--src
   | 
   +--test
   |
   +--capi
        | 
        +--include 
        |
        +--src 
        |
        Cargo.toml
```

`include` folder contains header files for C.

`src` contains the Rust files which are exported into C.

The Cargo manifest should be statically linked and have a dependency on the project foo. For example check out this [Cargo.toml](https://github.com/servo/html5ever/blob/master/capi/Cargo.toml) used in html5ever.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way Cargo can create this C library for me?

Cargo does not currently have this feature.

> I have a crate (e.g. html5ever), and I want Cargo to create a C library based on C-API for that crate.

Is there a reason that it is in C? C can call into Rust code directly, you could just use `html5ever` as it exists.

Comment: The problem at hand is, the thing guys at html5ever are trying to do is to have it's C-API created by Rust, so they can get rid of the Makefile whose only unique task is, creating C_API. Basically, move to Cargo, remove Makefile.

Comment: I'm surprised that Cargo doesn't allow some kind of CLI escape hatch.

Answer (score 0):

I think, [cargo-c](https://github.com/lu-zero/cargo-c) is excatly what you are looking for:

> It produces and installs a correct pkg-config file, a static library and a dynamic library, and a C header to be used by any C (and C-compatible) software.